# Pygame window doesn't show on Mac OS Catalina

Tags: macos, pygame, python-3.7

Running:
MacOS Catalina 10.15.3
Python 3.7.6.
Pygame 1.9.6

I just started programming and I am trying to run a reinforcement learning Pygame code (link: https://github.com/harvitronix/reinforcement-learning-car). When I run `python3.7 -m pygame.examples.aliens` I see the test window + sound and everything works.

However when I try to run the code for the game I am trying to get working I at first only saw the loading wheel, I fixed the loading wheel by putting in the following loop.  `

```
pygame.display.update()
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
```

When I try to run it now, I only see a black pygame window pop-up, so no loading wheel but also not the game, it also seems like the game doesn't run in the background (this was the case without the above loop). See the complete original code below:

```
import random
import math
import numpy as np

import pygame
from pygame.color import THECOLORS

import sys

import pymunk
from pymunk.vec2d import Vec2d
from pymunk.pygame_util import draw

# PyGame init
width = 1000
height = 700
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


# Turn off alpha since we don't use it.
screen.set_alpha(None)

# Showing sensors and redrawing slows things down.
show_sensors = True
draw_screen = True


class GameState:
    def __init__(self):
        # Global-ish.
        self.crashed = False

        # Physics stuff.
        self.space = pymunk.Space()
        self.space.gravity = pymunk.Vec2d(0., 0.)

        # Create the car.
        self.create_car(100, 100, 0.5)

        # Record steps.
        self.num_steps = 0

        # Create walls.
        static = [
            pymunk.Segment(
                self.space.static_body,
                (0, 1), (0, height), 1),
            pymunk.Segment(
                self.space.static_body,
                (1, height), (width, height), 1),
            pymunk.Segment(
                self.space.static_body,
                (width-1, height), (width-1, 1), 1),
            pymunk.Segment(
                self.space.static_body,
                (1, 1), (width, 1), 1)
        ]
        for s in static:
            s.friction = 1.
            s.group = 1
            s.collision_type = 1
            s.color = THECOLORS['red']
        self.space.add(static)

        # Create some obstacles, semi-randomly.
        # We'll create three and they'll move around to prevent over-fitting.
        self.obstacles = []
        self.obstacles.append(self.create_obstacle(200, 350, 100))
        self.obstacles.append(self.create_obstacle(700, 200, 125))
        self.obstacles.append(self.create_obstacle(600, 600, 35))

        # Create a cat.
        self.create_cat()

    def create_obstacle(self, x, y, r):
        c_body = pymunk.Body(pymunk.inf, pymunk.inf)
        c_shape = pymunk.Circle(c_body, r)
        c_shape.elasticity = 1.0
        c_body.position = x, y
        c_shape.color = THECOLORS["blue"]
        self.space.add(c_body, c_shape)
        return c_body

    def create_cat(self):
        inertia = pymunk.moment_for_circle(1, 0, 14, (0, 0))
        self.cat_body = pymunk.Body(1, inertia)
        self.cat_body.position = 50, height - 100
        self.cat_shape = pymunk.Circle(self.cat_body, 30)
        self.cat_shape.color = THECOLORS["orange"]
        self.cat_shape.elasticity = 1.0
        self.cat_shape.angle = 0.5
        direction = Vec2d(1, 0).rotated(self.cat_body.angle)
        self.space.add(self.cat_body, self.cat_shape)

    def create_car(self, x, y, r):
        inertia = pymunk.moment_for_circle(1, 0, 14, (0, 0))
        self.car_body = pymunk.Body(1, inertia)
        self.car_body.position = x, y
        self.car_shape = pymunk.Circle(self.car_body, 25)
        self.car_shape.color = THECOLORS["green"]
        self.car_shape.elasticity = 1.0
        self.car_body.angle = r
        driving_direction = Vec2d(1, 0).rotated(self.car_body.angle)
        self.car_body.apply_impulse(driving_direction)
        self.space.add(self.car_body, self.car_shape)

    def frame_step(self, action):
        if action == 0:  # Turn left.
            self.car_body.angle -= .2
        elif action == 1:  # Turn right.
            self.car_body.angle += .2

        # Move obstacles.
        if self.num_steps % 100 == 0:
            self.move_obstacles()

        # Move cat.
        if self.num_steps % 5 == 0:
            self.move_cat()

        driving_direction = Vec2d(1, 0).rotated(self.car_body.angle)
        self.car_body.velocity = 100 * driving_direction

        # Update the screen and stuff.
        screen.fill(THECOLORS["black"])
        draw(screen, self.space)
        self.space.step(1./10)
        if draw_screen:
            pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick()

        # Get the current location and the readings there.
        x, y = self.car_body.position
        readings = self.get_sonar_readings(x, y, self.car_body.angle)
        normalized_readings = [(x-20.0)/20.0 for x in readings] 
        state = np.array([normalized_readings])

        # Set the reward.
        # Car crashed when any reading == 1
        if self.car_is_crashed(readings):
            self.crashed = True
            reward = -500
            self.recover_from_crash(driving_direction)
        else:
            # Higher readings are better, so return the sum.
            reward = -5 + int(self.sum_readings(readings) / 10)
        self.num_steps += 1

        return reward, state

    def move_obstacles(self):
        # Randomly move obstacles around.
        for obstacle in self.obstacles:
            speed = random.randint(1, 5)
            direction = Vec2d(1, 0).rotated(self.car_body.angle + random.randint(-2, 2))
            obstacle.velocity = speed * direction

    def move_cat(self):
        speed = random.randint(20, 200)
        self.cat_body.angle -= random.randint(-1, 1)
        direction = Vec2d(1, 0).rotated(self.cat_body.angle)
        self.cat_body.velocity = speed * direction

    def car_is_crashed(self, readings):
        if readings[0] == 1 or readings[1] == 1 or readings[2] == 1:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def recover_from_crash(self, driving_direction):
        """
        We hit something, so recover.
        """
        while self.crashed:
            # Go backwards.
            self.car_body.velocity = -100 * driving_direction
            self.crashed = False
            for i in range(10):
                self.car_body.angle += .2  # Turn a little.
                screen.fill(THECOLORS["grey7"])  # Red is scary!
                draw(screen, self.space)
                self.space.step(1./10)
                if draw_screen:
                    pygame.display.flip()
                clock.tick()

    def sum_readings(self, readings):
        """Sum the number of non-zero readings."""
        tot = 0
        for i in readings:
            tot += i
        return tot

    def get_sonar_readings(self, x, y, angle):
        readings = []
        """
        Instead of using a grid of boolean(ish) sensors, sonar readings
        simply return N "distance" readings, one for each sonar
        we're simulating. The distance is a count of the first non-zero
        reading starting at the object. For instance, if the fifth sensor
        in a sonar "arm" is non-zero, then that arm returns a distance of 5.
        """
        # Make our arms.
        arm_left = self.make_sonar_arm(x, y)
        arm_middle = arm_left
        arm_right = arm_left

        # Rotate them and get readings.
        readings.append(self.get_arm_distance(arm_left, x, y, angle, 0.75))
        readings.append(self.get_arm_distance(arm_middle, x, y, angle, 0))
        readings.append(self.get_arm_distance(arm_right, x, y, angle, -0.75))

        if show_sensors:
            pygame.display.update()

        return readings

    def get_arm_distance(self, arm, x, y, angle, offset):
        # Used to count the distance.
        i = 0

        # Look at each point and see if we've hit something.
        for point in arm:
            i += 1

            # Move the point to the right spot.
            rotated_p = self.get_rotated_point(
                x, y, point[0], point[1], angle + offset
            )

            # Check if we've hit something. Return the current i (distance)
            # if we did.
            if rotated_p[0] <= 0 or rotated_p[1] <= 0 \
                    or rotated_p[0] >= width or rotated_p[1] >= height:
                return i  # Sensor is off the screen.
            else:
                obs = screen.get_at(rotated_p)
                if self.get_track_or_not(obs) != 0:
                    return i

            if show_sensors:
                pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255, 255, 255), (rotated_p), 2)

        # Return the distance for the arm.
        return i

    def make_sonar_arm(self, x, y):
        spread = 10  # Default spread.
        distance = 20  # Gap before first sensor.
        arm_points = []
        # Make an arm. We build it flat because we'll rotate it about the
        # center later.
        for i in range(1, 40):
            arm_points.append((distance + x + (spread * i), y))

        return arm_points

    def get_rotated_point(self, x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2, radians):
        # Rotate x_2, y_2 around x_1, y_1 by angle.
        x_change = (x_2 - x_1) * math.cos(radians) + \
            (y_2 - y_1) * math.sin(radians)
        y_change = (y_1 - y_2) * math.cos(radians) - \
            (x_1 - x_2) * math.sin(radians)
        new_x = x_change + x_1
        new_y = height - (y_change + y_1)
        return int(new_x), int(new_y)

    def get_track_or_not(self, reading):
        if reading == THECOLORS['black']:
            return 0
        else:
            return 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    game_state = GameState()
    while True:
        game_state.frame_step((random.randint(0, 2)))
```

I don't think the issue is with my python version because the test runs normal. Anybody see the issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. I put the loop in the beginning of the code but it should have gone beneath:

```
if draw_screen:
            pygame.display.flip()
```